# why my git client cannot push/uploaded png/tar/jpg type file to repo

Tags: git

I have add and commit one test file, for example, test.png, when git push, everything seems fine, but check in the remote repo, the test.png file is not added there, I need to push all related files to the remote to add one new file to remote repo:

```
git lfs push origin <branch_name> --all
```

I checked in my .gitattributes file, the png type is support there:

```
*.[pP][nN][gG] filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

Config my git client as following cannot fix the problem either:

```
git config lfs.allowincompletepush 1
```

why this happen, is there a simple way to let me push png/tar/jpg or other binary files successfully?

Comment: maybe there is a restriction on the remote repository. usually you shouldn't push jar or large files to git, you kinda of defy it's purpose.

Comment: @Opri yes, but when use git lfs push origin <branch_name> --all to push all the lfs items, it can then be added successfully, not sure how to check the  restriction on the remote repository